# Is there a way to combine a file with crontab?

Tags: cron

I'm trying to create an interface that will show a message on the screen every set time. Cron is an ideal tool for this case only it doesn't read data from a file during it's run (as far as I could tell). I could create a bunch of file to read but this is redundant.

Is there a way to add a line into the user crontab file or remove a line from it after I have read it from a file?

Comment: I can't really see how your first paragraph connects to your second. What exactly are you trying to accomplish? "show a message on the screen every set time" is trivial; is the message changing each time? Does the contents of the message come from a file?

Comment: I've difficulties to understand what you really want, but I wonder if `at` wouldn't be a better solution than modifying the crontab.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always write a cronjob that calls a script that conditionally calls `crontab -l > oldcrontab` and then executes `crontab file`. Where `file` would be the new crontab that should be installed, constructed from oldcrontab modulo an appended/removed line.